# English for "prolongement" or "Fortsetzung"?

Tags: functions, terminology, translation-request, mathematical-french, mathematical-german

I'm sorry if that's not the right place to ask for, wikipedia failed to give me the correct word...

What's the English for a function that is defined on a larger domain than the original function and coincides with it on the original domain? Is it "extension" or "continuation" or something else?

Comment: "Analytische Fortsetzung" means analytic continuation, to give an example.

Comment: Thanks every one, for the almost instantaneaous answer!!

Comment: If $A\subsetneq B$ and $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to C$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in A$, then $g$ is an _extension_ of $f$ and $f$ is a _restriction_ of $g$.  I've seen "continuation" used only for holomorphic functions, whereas "extension" and "restriction" are used in set theory and therefore used in everything. One can say $g$ extends $f$ to $B$ and $f$ restricts $g$ to $A$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Dear @MichaelHardy : are you entering the comment thread from the review queue, possibly?

Comment: @rschwieb : I have no idea at all what you mean by the review queue. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Dear @MichaelHardy : I was just looking for reasons to explain why one would consider posting a comment consisting entirely of things (shall we say "semantically verbatim") that were posted as solutions two hours previously. Observing questions from the review queue obscures the other answers, so that would be a natural explanation. No matter... Regards

Comment: @rschwieb : I thought I had ascertained that they were not posted, but I didn't feel like posting an answer when one had already been accepted.  As far as I knew my comment went beyond what had been posted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both "extension" and "continuation" are OK. I would be inclined to reserve "continuation" for the analytic continuation of analytic functions (or similar cases where the extension is somehow determined by its restriction to the original domain).

Comment: @rschwieb: that's because your answer was an *extension* (and not just a continuation) of mine and so took you longer to type $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Hopefully my answer wasn't too prolonged :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, if $X\subset Y$ and $f:X\to Z$ and $g: Y\to Z$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$, it is possible to call $g$ an extension of $f$, or to just say that "$g$ extends $f$."

"Continuation" connotes that the extension is somehow generated by the function and the subset, but in most cases a general function could be defined quite arbitrarily outside of $X$, so it does not seem to be a good substitute for "extension."

If you'd like to know the counterpart to the phrase "$g$ extends $f$," then we would speak of "restriction." That is, "$f$ is equal to the restriction of $g$ to the set $X$."